# Cloud Functions are unable to establish a connection with the Memorystore Redis instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a 2nd generation Cloud Functions that I'd like to connect with a Memorystore Redis instance. Following the official documentation meticulously, I attempted the connection steps, yet encountered a `TimeoutError`. Considering a possible error or omission on my part, I explored the integration option provided by the Cloud Run service. Unfortunately, this approach also resulted in a persistent `TimeoutError`. I'm completely baffled by why it isn't functioning. While I could comprehend issues when following the official documentation, I was genuinely surprised that even GCP's integration failed to work. Has anyone here encountered this issue before? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you configured VPC ? https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-functions#configuring